# Is it possible to stream m3u8 video playlist in android 2.3 devices?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I tried a lot of alternatives to achieve live video streaming a m3u8 playlist for 2.3 version of android but couldn't do it. Can anybody give suggestions for the same. TIA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't play m3u8 with an Android version older than 3.0 without using vitamio player.

You can download it from this url 
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9s65mxj67ix4t3d/Vitamio-SDK.7z?dl=1
just download it and add this library your project.